# Prevent multiple row selection in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the following XAML markup in a WPF DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="7" Height="150" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="gvResults" 
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="590" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="gvResults_SelectionChanged"
           SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="190" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Surname" Width="190" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is it possible to prevent users from selecting multiple rows while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or selecting multiple rows with a mouse?

I've tried the following code in the SelectionChanged event but it does not work:

```
private void gvResults_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (gvResults.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try specifying `<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"`
and optionally `SelectionUnit="FullRow"`

The available options for SelectionMode are

- Single
- Extended

and for SelectionUnit are

- Cell
- FullRow
- CellOrRowHeader